# ProFTPD, creating or modifying a file gives 550: Operation not permitted

Tags: centos, plesk, proftpd

I'm using a centos 6.9 with PLESK Onyx server. Since yesterday my ftp service is broken.
Everytime i want to create or edit a file it gives me a 550 error. But when i want to create a directory, change permissions, open a file or delete a file it works fine.

I've checked groups and password file (etc/group, etc/passwd). But everything seems to be ok. 
I've changed the permissions of a sub-folder and tried to create a file but that didn't work either.

Hopefully someone can push me in the right direction.

proftpd.conf:

```
#
# To have more informations about Proftpd configuration
# look at : http://www.proftpd.org/
#

# This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file (rename it to
# 'proftpd.conf' for actual use.  It establishes a single server
# and a single anonymous login.  It assumes that you have a user/group
# "nobody" and "ftp" for normal operation and anon.

ServerName                      "ProFTPD"
#ServerType                     standalone
ServerType                      inetd
DefaultServer                   on

<Global>
DefaultRoot     ~               psacln
AllowOverwrite          on
PassivePorts 50000 60000
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
        # common settings for all virtual hosts
        TLSEngine on
        TLSRequired off

        TLSLog /var/log/plesk/ftp_tls.log

        TLSRSACertificateFile /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/httpsd.pem
        TLSRSACertificateKeyFile /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/httpsd.pem

        # Authenticate clients that want to use FTP over TLS?
        TLSVerifyClient off

        # Allow SSL/TLS renegotiations when the client requests them, but
        # do not force the renegotations.  Some clients do not support
        # SSL/TLS renegotiations; when mod_tls forces a renegotiation, these
        # clients will close the data connection, or there will be a timeout
        # on an idle data connection.
        TLSRenegotiate none

        # As of ProFTPD 1.3.3rc1, mod_tls only accepts SSL/TLS data connections
        # that reuse the SSL session of the control connection, as a security measure.
        # Unfortunately, there are some clients (e.g. curl) which do not reuse SSL sessions.
        TLSOptions NoSessionReuseRequired
</IfModule>
</Global>

DefaultTransferMode     binary
UseFtpUsers                     on

TimesGMT                        off
SetEnv TZ :/etc/localtime
# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                            21
# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask                           022

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances                    30

#Following part of this config file were generate by PSA automatically
#Any changes in this part will be overwritten by next manipulation
#with Anonymous FTP feature in PSA control panel.

#Include directive should point to place where FTP Virtual Hosts configurations
#preserved


# Primary log file mest be outside of system logrotate province

TransferLog /var/log/plesk/xferlog

#Change default group for new files and directories in vhosts dir to psacln

<Directory /var/www/vhosts>
        GroupOwner      psacln
</Directory>

# Enable PAM authentication
AuthPAM on
AuthPAMConfig proftpd

IdentLookups off
UseReverseDNS off

AuthGroupFile   /etc/group

Include /etc/proftpd.d/*.conf
Include /etc/proftpd.include
#Scoreboard
```

**Update**
I think it's not an FTP related problem. I think the problem comes from an upload protection. 
I've checked the server, but there is no ClamAV running. Are there any default antivirus services running on CentOS?

**Update**
Found the issue, there was a roaming clamAv config file on the server that was included by the proftpd conf. But since clamAv had been removed it could not connect thus failing every edit.

Luckily its solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, there was a roaming clamAv config file on the server that was included by the proftpd conf. But since clamAv had been removed it could not connect thus failing every edit